# Sort DataList by calcualated/aggregated column

Tags: php, sorting, silverstripe, datalist

is it possible to sort a Datalist/ComponentSet by an calculated/virtual/aggregated col?

I have a DataList containing events having a StartDate and EndDate.
Now i want to sort the list by duration of the event (shortest to longest).

In SQL i would do:

```
... ORDER BY DATEDIFF(EndDate, StartDate) ASC
```

How to do that with silverstripe ORM

```
$list = Event::get()->sort('????');
```

An additional column containing a new Field Duration and filling this field in onAfterWrite-hooks is not preferred.

Is this possible ?

Robert

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$list = Event::get()->sort(array('DATEDIFF("EndDate", "StartDate")' => 'ASC'));
```

`DataList::sort` doesn't do any escaping, so any valid ORDER BY clause will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT StartDate,EndDate,DATEDIFF(EndDate, StartDate) AS DiffDate FROM myTable ORDER BY DiffDate ASC
```

U can calculate this diff in select to show it and order, i use 'AS DiffDate' to simplify

Comment: sry for not beeing clear. The sorting should be handled by silverstripe ORM ... not classic sql

Answer (score 1):

You could use it like this:

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(EndDate, StartDate) as duration FROM table WHERE conditional = 1 ORDER BY duration ASC
```

Comment: sry for not beeing clear. The sorting should be handled by silverstripe ORM ... not classic sql